# Taking Snapshot of a PDF using Python

Tags: python, image, pdf, png

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a PDF to a series of images with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331918/converting-a-pdf-to-a-series-of-images-with-python)

I know the code to open a PDF file using Python:

```
import os
os.startfile('C:\file_name.pdf')
```

My query is that whether it is possible for me to save a particular page of the pdf file as an image file (jpeg, png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look helpful for you: [Converting a PDF to a series of images with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331918/converting-a-pdf-to-a-series-of-images-with-python)

Comment: ya. The swftools had to be installed and then I copied the gfx.pyd file to C:\Python26\Lib\ folder and then called the inbuild operations in the gfx module. Thanks.