# pytesseract and image.tif file

Tags: python, python-tesseract, pytesser

I need to transcribe an image.tif with several pages to text using pytesseract.
I have the next code:

```
> From PIL import Image
> Import pytesseract
> Pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C: / Program Files (x86) / Tesseract-
> OCR / tesseract '
> Print (pytesseract.image_to_string (Image.open ('CAMARA.tif'), lang = "spa"))
```

The problem is that only extract the firs page. How can i extract all of them?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix the same problem by calling the method `convert()` as below

```
image = Image.open(imagePath).convert("RGBA")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have mentioned only one image "camara.tif" , First you have to convert all the pdf pages into images you can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331918/converting-a-pdf-to-a-series-of-images-with-python) for doing so.

And next use pytesseract to loop over images one by one to extract text from image.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over the same problem... what you could do is call tesseract directly

```
# test.py
import subprocess

in_filename = 'file_0.tiff'
out_filename = 'out'
lang = 'spa'
subprocess.call(['tesseract', in_filename, '-l', lang, out_filename ])
```

would process all pages

```
$ python test.py 
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0-beta.1 with Leptonica
Page 1
Page 2
Page 3
```