# Extracting scanned pages from PDF using python

Tags: python, pdf

I have a lot of `PDF` files, which are basically scanned documents so every page is one scanned image. I want to perform `OCR` and extract text from those files. I have tried `pytesseract` but it does not perform `OCR` directly on `pdf` files so as a work around, I want to extract the `images` from `PDF` files, save them in directory and then perform `OCR` using `pytesseract` on those images directly. Is there any way in python to extract scanned images from `pdf` files? or is there any way to perform `OCR` directly on pdf files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been addressed in previous Stack Overflow Posts.

[Converting PDF to images automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002055/converting-pdf-to-images-automatically)
[Converting a PDF to a series of images with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331918/converting-a-pdf-to-a-series-of-images-with-python)

Here is a script that may be helpful: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/extracting_jpgs_from_pdfs.html

Another method: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/427722/convert-pdf-to-image-with-pythonmagick

Please check previous posts before asking a question.

EDIT:

Including working script for future reference. Program works for Python3.6 on Windows:

```
# coding=utf-8
# Extract jpg's from pdf's. Quick and dirty.

import sys

with open("Link/To/PDF/File.pdf", "rb") as file:
    pdf = file.read()

startmark = b"\xff\xd8"
startfix = 0
endmark = b"\xff\xd9"
endfix = 2
i = 0

njpg = 0
while True:
    istream = pdf.find(b"stream", i)
    if istream < 0:
        break
    istart = pdf.find(startmark, istream, istream + 20)
    if istart < 0:
        i = istream + 20
        continue
    iend = pdf.find(b"endstream", istart)
    if iend < 0:
        raise Exception("Didn't find end of stream!")
    iend = pdf.find(endmark, iend - 20)
    if iend < 0:
        raise Exception("Didn't find end of JPG!")

    istart += startfix
    iend += endfix
    print("JPG %d from %d to %d" % (njpg, istart, iend))
    jpg = pdf[istart:iend]
    with open("jpg%d.jpg" % njpg, "wb") as jpgfile:
        jpgfile.write(jpg)

    njpg += 1
    i = iend
```

Comment: I couldn't find any method that is working with Python 3.6. I am using Anaconda on Windows.

Comment: I just ran the code from the comments section of the example script I linked to (https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/extracting_jpgs_from_pdfs.html). I was able to get it working on my Windows Machine running Python 3.6. Let me know if you are still having issues.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Yes this one is working fine. Upovting.

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help!

Comment: Works on Kubuntu 22.04 running Python 3.10.7 .Thanks.